# Как можно убрать обратный transtion delay?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть два блока: один закрывает другой. При наведении на контейнер первый сдвигается, устапая место второму, который в этот обретает форму.

В принципе, все работает:

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
  
}
.wrap{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition:1s;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.container:hover>.wrap{
  right:40px;
}
.container:hover>button{
  opacity:1;
}
button{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  opacity:0;
  transition:1s 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap"></div>
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

Но как только я убираю курсор, то кнопка начинает исчезать только через время , заданное в transition-delay. Как я могу в этом моменте отменить transition-delay?

Я пробовал поставить

```
.container:hover>.wrap{
  transition: 1s 1s;
  right:40px;
}
```

Но таким образом почему-то перекрывается основной transition, и не происходит основного эффекта (блоки накладываются друг на друга при появлении).

Есть какой-то способ убрать transition-delay на время "unhover" технически?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 1s;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container:hover>.wrap {
  right: 40px;
}

.container:hover>button {
  transition: 1.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap"></div>
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
  
}
.wrap{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition:1s;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.container:hover>.wrap{
  right:40px;
}
.container:hover>button{
  animation: show-button 1s 0.5s forwards;
}
button{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  opacity:0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes show-button {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap"></div>
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```